# How do I add block configuration information for themes using features?

Tags: 7, features

Is it possible to use features to manage block configuration information (for example, the positioning of a block [header, footer, etc.]) using features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not directly you need to use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module to do it.